# how to validate integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, aiogram

My bot asks a user to enter an integer. There're two options for user to do this:

1. the integer must be > 0 and < 31
2. the integer must be > 0 and < 185

I wrote a code which validates user's input but my bot falls silent after the second attempt. How to fix it?

main function recieves input from user:

```
async def _save_data(user_data: str, state: FSMContext, type: str):
    data = await state.get_data()
    user_id = data['user']
    try:
        validate_date(user_data, type)
    except (InvalidDate, ValueError) as error:
        await bot.send_message(user_id, error)
    except Exception as e:
        await bot.send_message(user_id, messages.error_message.format(e))
    else:
       ### saves to the DB
```

function which validates user's input:

```
def validate_date(user_date: str, record_type: str):
    match record_type:
        case 'month':
            try:
                if int(user_date) > 31 or int(user_date) <= 0:
                    raise InvalidDate(messages.invalid_month_message)
            except ValueError:
                raise InvalidDate(messages.invalid_digits_message)
        case 'every_few_days':
            if int(user_date) > 185:
                raise InvalidDate(messages.invalid_days_message)
        case 'once':
            if datetime.strptime(user_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date() < datetime.today().date():
                raise InvalidDate(messages.invalid_calendar_date)
```

by the way it works correctly in the case 'once' and the bot sends the calendar to the user as many times as requiered for the user to choose the right date

function which sends the calendar:

```
async def receive_calendar_date(date: datetime, state: FSMContext, user_id: int):
    data = await state.get_data()
    date_to_save = ''
    try:
        validate_date(str(date), data['type'])        
    except InvalidDate as e:
        await bot.send_message(user_id, e, reply_markup=await SimpleCalendar().start_calendar())
    else:
        ### saves user's data
```

InvalidDate:

```
class InvalidDate(Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: You only need to call `int(user_date)` *once*; if it's not an `int` the first time, it won't be the next time, either. `try: user_date = int(user_date) except ValueError: raise InvalidDate("not an integer")`. Then the rest of your code can focus on whether `user_date_` is in the appropriate range.

Comment: @chepner I edited my code as you said and my bot still falling silence if I enter invalid integer second time :(